# Relation between $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ and $\int_{a}^{b} (1-f(x)) dx$

Tags: integration, functions

Say you're expected to work out $\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \sin^2(x) dx$ solely from the result $\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \cos^2(x) dx$. It can be transformed into $\int_{0}^{\pi/3} (1-\cos^2(x)) dx$, but then what?

Comment: Then use "linearity" of integrals.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_a^b (1-f(x))dx=\int_a^b1dx-\int_a^bf(x)dx=b-a-\int_a^bf(x)dx$.

Therefore, $\int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_a^b(1-f(x))dx=b-a$.

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

We use the linearity of integrals to rewrite that as
$$\int_0^{\pi/3} dx - \int_0^{\pi/3}\cos^2x dx.$$
Next, we use the identity
$$\cos^2x =\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\cos(2x)\right)$$
to rewrite this integral as 
$$\int_0^{\pi/3} dx - \int_0^{\pi/3}\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\cos(2x)\right) dx.$$
Split this up again using linearity:
$$\int_0^{\pi/3} dx - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/3}dx - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/3}\cos(2x) dx.$$
Then we can compute each integral -- the first 2 we compute directly using antidifferentiation, and the third integral using the substitution $u=2x$.